# Override model save to send request along with post_save

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

**Problem**

Django models send the signal `post_save` when a model is saved. The `post_save`, however, does not have access to the request object. I need to access variables like `request.user` and send it with the signal.

**Possible solutions**

- Admin - Override admin `save_model` to send `post_save` with some extra parameters from the request object.
- DRF API - After a model is created or updated, send `post_save`, again with parameters from the request object.

**Question**

In both the above cases, `model.save()` will send the `post_save` by default. How can I override `save` to either send a custom signal or resend `post_save` with `request.user`. How should this be done?

Comment: Are you sure you want a `post_save` signal? If you need to access `request`, you should probably define custom signal and manually call it from the view.

Comment: @НазарТопольський I wanted to use `post_save` because it is the default signal. But I am open to any other viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the user object this way on the User model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# post save for creating customer on user saving
def post_save_function(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    # create customer instance 
    if created:



post_save.connect(post_save_function, sender=User)
```

You will have access to the `User` in the `instance` variable

Comment: I guess you did not understand my question.

Comment: All django models emit `post_save` signals. I want to send (resend) these signals, through the DRF API or Django admin, but with an additional `request.user` parameter.